# Outlook OWA addin ribbon icon text

Tags: outlook-addin, office-js, outlook-web-addins

is it in any way possible to be allowed to have text by your addin ribbon icon in Outlook OWA? it is something that would be very valuable for our addin

[image: as described here, red circle is how it looks now, blue circle is what we would like]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how Outlook development team decided to display add-ins list and cannot be changed. On hover `tooltip` shows `DisplayName` from your manifest, but this about it.  If this is valuable feature you would like to request, you should post it at [https://officespdev.uservoice.com](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback?category_id=131778).